# Modificar createdAt y updatedAt en Sequelize y SQLite

Tags: sqlite, update, sequelize

En una aplicación que utiliza Node JS y Sequelize con SQLite para guardar datos locales quiero modificar los timestamps generados por defecto (createdAt y updatedAt), he intentado con un par de opciones, sin embargo no he logrado hacerlo correctamente, la forma en la que lo estoy realizando es la siguiente:

```js
        let fechaHora = DateTime.now().setZone("America/Mexico_City").toJSDate();      
        let orders = await db.Order.findAll({ where: cond, order: [['id', 'ASC']]});
        for(let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {


            let order = orders[i];

            try {
 
          //Aqui he intentado cambiando a updatedAt, pero tampoco se cambia el valor
                order.changed('createdAt', true);
                order.set('createdAt', fechaHora, {raw: true});
                await order.save({
                    silent: true,
                    fields: ['createdAt']
                });
             } catch (error) {
                 console.error(error);
             }
```

También intenté con este código:

```js
            try {
                order = await db.Order.update(
                    { createdAt: fechaHora,
                        updatedAt: fechaHora },
                    { where: { id: order.dataValues.id } }
                    );
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
```